# Getting images to use for Android development

Tags: java, android, png, drawable, sprite

I'm developing a game for a college project and need to get some sprites. I've searched online but can only seem to find old SNES style ones.

I'm looking for a moving football (or any ball but preferably a football) and player & goalkeeper PNG images. Also, I'm wondering if I can simply just place these in the drawable resource folder in Android and then call them in my `SurfaceView`?

I want to get a bit better quality that old console games though. Does anyone know a good site that has something like this?